# Dajngo Rest Framework how to set field to no required

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this code and i want to set `content` field to be not required.

```
type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(default=ComponentType.MediaComponent.value)
content = ContentSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = MediaComponent
    fields = ['id'] + ComponentSerializer.Meta.fields + ['type', 'content']
```

Answer (score 0):

add `extra_kwargs` in Meta class or add `required=false` to content serializer like below

```
type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(default=ComponentType.MediaComponent.value)
content = ContentSerializer(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = MediaComponent
    fields = ['id'] + ComponentSerializer.Meta.fields + ['type', 'content']
```

Or

```
type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(default=ComponentType.MediaComponent.value)
content = ContentSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = MediaComponent
    fields = ['id'] + ComponentSerializer.Meta.fields + ['type', 'content']
    extra_kwargs = {"content": {"required": False}}
```

Comment: the first one is working but at the second way i have this error {'content': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]},

Comment: What is your payload request?